# Who is the 9th Shiva?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana

There are supposed to be more than one aspect of Lord Shiva. Sri Hanuman is Rudra, the 11<sup>th</sup> aspect of Lord Shiva, can someone shed some light on the other aspects of lord Shiva? In particular the 9<sup>th</sup>.

Thank you.

Comment: They are Rudras. There are 11 rudras . They are the children of Aditi and Kashyapa. It is not an aspect.